# How to convert arrayList to string separated by hyphen

Tags: java, string

I have String ArrayList has some elements but I need to convert it to string each element is separated from other by -
this is the arrayList

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("a");
items.add("b");
items.add("c");
:
:
```

I need to get the string like this

> "a-b-c-..."

Comment: Create a `StringBuilder` object and use `append` to attached each string, then convert the StringBuilder to a String. Use `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` if code is synchronized.

Comment: Oh good. but there is no method like implode in php

Comment: Are you writing this in php or java?

Comment: sure on java . but I have told you about php this problem sove by implode("-",array);  and I am looking for like this in java
 
please see the accepted answer. any way I appreciated your help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 you can use the `join` function of the `String` class:

```
String result = String.join("-", items);
```

If you are programming for Android, Java 8 is not available. You can instead use:

```
String result = TextUtils.join("-", items);
```

Comment: Learn something new about java 8 everyday. Thanks!

Comment: Oooh fancy. This is a great tip.

Comment: wow this is a great way thanks so much

Comment: hey bro. this method does not work. can not resolve method join

Comment: @NahamSoft are you using Java 8?

Comment: @Shadow ( version 8 update 25 ( build 1.8.0_25-b18)

Comment: @NahamSoft are you by chance doing this on Android?

Comment: @Shadow I do not understand what did you mean.

Comment: @NahamSoft Mobile Phone Development, or PC?

Comment: @Shadow Mobile phone. but I am sorry bro how can I know whats java am I using?

Comment: @Shadow how can I know what java I am using in android studio

Comment: @NahamSoft in Mobile you can't use Java 8. Instead of `String.join("-", items)` you will need to use `TextUtils.join("-", items)`

Comment: it works fine now thanks so much bro

Comment: It saved much of my time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

One line:

```
String allItems = String.join("-", items);
```

Documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-).

Comment: thanks so much bor. this is what am I looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Joiner` from google-guava:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("a");
items.add("b");
items.add("c");

String result = Joiner.on("-").join(items);
```

here is the link - https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#joiner

Comment: This is a nice one liner, but probably a bit overkill if they aren't already using guava

Comment: Well, good time to start using it)

Comment: I am looking for method like implode in php and this is what I am looking for.thanks so much. this is the accepted answer. good luck bro

Comment: @NahamSoft You can find such functionality in pure Java 8 without using 3rd party libraries (Guava) so if you are using Java 8 it will be better to accept the other answer which has already couple of upvotes.

Comment: @ctomek do know another function is better ?  what is it ? . and thanks for your help

Comment: @NahamSoft See an answer from Shadow.

Comment: @ctomek thanks for your attention. I had not see it then.I have edit the accepted answer

Comment: @KhalidovOleg how can I know what java I am using in android studio ?

Comment: @NahamSoft it's in the settings. Anyway, it cannot be `java-8` due to android doesn't support it yes. So `google-guava` is the way you can handle your question

Answer (score 2):

No guava libs will be possible by manipulating the `toString` result

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.add("a");
        items.add("b");
        items.add("c");
        System.out.println(items.toString().replace(", ", "-"));
        // no [ ] 
        System.out.println(items.toString().substring(1, items.toString().length() - 1).replace(", ", "-"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    items.add("a");
    items.add("b");
    items.add("c");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(items.get(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < items.size(); i++) {
        builder.append("-").append(items.get(i));
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
    System.out.println(""+ result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(items.get(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < items.size(); i++) {
        builder.append("-").append(items.get(i));
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
```

Comment: its ok like this.but is there a method like implode in php

Comment: please see the accepted answer.
 
any way I appreciated your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function for this

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("a");
items.add("b");
items.add("c");

Log.d("myFormattedList",getFormattedString(items));

private String getFormattedString() {
    String tempString = "";
    for (String temp: items) {
        tempString += temp;
    }
    tempString.substring(0,str.length()-1); //remove last char "-"
    return tempString;
}
```

Comment: please see the accepted answer. any way I appreciated your help